# Registering script with User Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, ascx, registerstartupscript

I have an asp.net webforms application that I am working on. It uses a main aspx page to create a layout, and then uses ascx pages within a panel to display data.

What I need to do is use javascript with a user control (ascx files).

I thought that having a script manager on the main aspx page would allow me to register scripts in the Page_Load function on the .ascx pages.

Here is a basic example of what I am trying to do:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim csConsoleLogSomething As String = "ConsoleLogSomethingScript"
    Dim consoleLogScript As String = "function logSomething() {  console.log('SOMETHING'); }"
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Me.Page.ClientScript
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), csConsoleLogSomething, consoleLogScript, True)
    'I have also tried using: Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Me.Parent.Page.ClientScript

End Sub
```

Here is the HTML on the ascx page:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="btnWTF" type="button" onclick="logSomething()" value="DO SOMETHING FOR THE LOVE OF MOSES" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the script manager declaration on the main aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I have also tried to create a simple alert to come up on the page load, but I cannot get any of my script to execute. When I push the button I get 'ReferenceError: logSomething is not defined'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For kicks I also just tried this method to no avail:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Button1, Button1.GetType(), csConsoleLogSomething, consoleLogScript, True)
```

The buttons HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
```

This resulted in a post to the main aspx page. Nothing was logged to the console. If possible I would like to stay away from asp controls. The end goal is to get jQuery integrated into this application.

Comment: Would you please post more about your ASP page (including the area that you insert your control)? I might have a guess..

Comment: We are using a main.aspx page that is essentially a layout for the system. Ascx pages are used within the aspx page - so, the control isn't on an aspx page unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've reached the result you wanted.

My Aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="btnWTF" type="button" onclick="logSomething()" value="DO SOMETHING FOR THE LOVE OF MOSES" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My codebehind:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "function logSomething() {  alert('SOMETHING'); }", True)
 End Sub
```

Probably your call to the ScriptManager as object wasn't correct. You don't need to add the ScriptManager to a variable, you just call it directly through the ScriptManager object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. However, the page that needs to execute javascript is an ascx (User Control) page. Also, thanks for the edit on my question!

Comment: It will work anyway. You can still use the Page object as parameter. I've just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your control has an `UpdatePanel` as parent.
If that doesn't work, keep that there and then try registering the script on your page first and check if the script is called on page load.

Based on your comments, it would be better to have pages and a `MasterPage` as your frame instead of using controls to have *sub pages*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Rafael has solved this for me. If I could upvote I would - I just made the account so I do not have enough reputation to do so